# Kivy: setting the color of text on a disabled button in kv

Tags: button, text, colors, kivy

I'm trying to set the color of the text on a disabled button separate from the normal color of the button text. As buttons are based on Label i tried to change disabled_color but with out success.
As you can see in the image the font color of the disabled button (left) is still the same as the normal button right. [Disabled (left) and normal (right) botton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiZ2K.png) Please help me set the text color correct.
I`m using python 3.7.3 and kivy 1.10.1

```
Button:
    #Set font
    font_size: '35sp'
    color: 1,1,1,1
    disabled_color: 25.0/255.0,25.0/255.0,25.0/255.0,1
    #Set background
    background_normal: 'button_normal.png'
    background_down: 'button_down.png'
    background_disabled_normal: 'button_normal_disn.png'
    background_disabled_down: 'button_normal_disd.png'
```

Answer (score 0):

That's strange: disabled_color works fine for me. Are you sure the first button in your image is disabled? Thats my code for testing - maybe it helps.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.atlas import Atlas

kv= Builder.load_string('''
<MainScreen>
    first_but:first_but
    orientation:"vertical"
    Button:
        id: first_but
        font_size: '35sp'
        color: 1,0,1,1
        disabled_color: 100.0/255.0,100.0/255.0,25.0/255.0,1
        text: root.enabled
        on_release: print("working")
    Button:
        font_size: '35sp'
        color: 1,0,1,1
        text: "toggle enablement of upper button"
        on_release: root.toggle_enable()

''')
class MainScreen(BoxLayout):
    first_but = ObjectProperty(None)
    enabled = StringProperty("enabled")

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def toggle_enable(self):
        if self.enabled == "enabled":
            self.enabled = "disabled"
            self.first_but.disabled = True
        else:
            self.enabled = "enabled"
            self.first_but.disabled = False

class myApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myApp().run()
```

Comment: Thank you for your code. It helped me track down the issue. There was something wrong with my installation. I reinstalled everything from kivy and now get the expected results.